# Add SHA256 Digests to RPM Packages

Tags: linux, hash, sha256, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to add the SHA256 digests for header and payload to my RPM packages.

currently, it is building with sha1 digest.

below is the output for
`rpm --checksig --verbose pkg_name.rpm`

```
    Header SHA1 digest: OK
    MD5 digest: OK
```

Environment - **RHEL6**

Here is what I tried so far

- Upgrade the RPM to version 4.14.3. which supports the sha256 as default algo for digests.
- override macros for the digest algorithm by adding the below lines in $HOME/.rpmmacros file or /etc/rpm/macros file [reference](https://www.starlab.io/blog/adding-sha256-digests-to-rpms)

```
%_source_filedigest_algorithm 8
%_binary_filedigest_algorithm 8
```

- Add the above macros in **pkg.spec** file as below which is being passed to **rpmbuild** command

```
%define _source_filedigest_algorithm 8
%define _binary_filedigest_algorithm 8
```

but none of the above solutions worked for me
and after rebuilding I still see my package is building with sha1 and md5 as digest algo.

please note the output of `rpm --showrc | grep "digest_algo"` command for each of the above solution is as below

```
-13: _binary_filedigest_algorithm       8
-13: _source_filedigest_algorithm       8
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the file **.rpmmacros** in the home folder of the user which builds the RPM package and put this content in this file:

```
%_gpg_name My Key ID
%_gpg_digest_algo sha256
%_binary_filedigest_algorithm SHA256
%_source_filedigest_algorithm SHA256 
%__gpg_sign_cmd %{__gpg} \
gpg --force-v3-sigs --batch --no-verbose --no-armor --passphrase "%{getenv:KEYPASSWORD}" \
%{?_gpg_digest_algo:--digest-algo %{_gpg_digest_algo}} \
--no-secmem-warning \
-u "%{_gpg_name}" -sbo %{__signature_filename} %{__plaintext_filename}
```

- Replace "`My Key ID`" with the name of the generated GPG key
- Set the environment variable `KEYPASSWORD`

Then you can add a signature with the following command:

```
rpmsign --addsign package.rpm
```

*NOTE:* You need rpm >= **4.14.3**